# Signal the end of a Queue?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7 here.

In the [Queue example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), the threads run indefinitely:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Is there an "official" or recommended way to tell the threads to exit after `q.join()` without using a global variable or subclassing `Thread`?

Currently, I am doing something like:

```
class MyThread(Thread, object):
    ...

    def run(self):
        ...
        while True:
            try:
                item = self.q.get_nowait()
            except Queue.Empty:
                if self.is_queue_empty:
                    break
            else:
                ...

...
threads = [MyThread(q, target) for _ in range(num_threads)]
...
q.join()
for thread in threads:
    thread.is_queue_empty = True
```

It works, but it seems kind of hacky. I would also like to avoid making a list of threads, if possible.

Comment: I can't speak for the best "Pythonic" way to do this, but streams of data usually have some kind of "magic byte" or specialized value to denote that the end of the stream has been reached. When reading a file, this might be `EOF`, while reading from a socket this would be something like the "socket closed" OS event, while other protocols might send the length of bytes to be read in advance (in addition to or instead of a specialized value).

Comment: `queue.join()`  is kind of a barrier. It just blocks the current thread until a `task_done` has been called for every time `put` was called. It seems to me that you're looking for a way to **cancel** threads still running after a certain point.